# mod_rewrite - trouble with combination of rules

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've got the following rules to work which:

- only act on files that exist
- exclude any files that contain images|js|css in their uri
- add trailing slash to request uri

Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(images|js|css)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/.])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I now need to correctly redirect my home uri's like so:

`http://www.example.com/sitemap/` -> `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=sitemap`

I've tried the following approach:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/.])$ index.php?page=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

But I get a page not found, presumably because $1 is being fed something with a slash in it. I thought `[^/]` would remove it but apparently not.

Could someone explain where I am going wrong here please?

Comment: Why do you need **redirect** (URL will change in browser)? Usually people want to keep "nice" URL and just rewrite URL (internal redirect) when URL remains unchanged in browser. Is that intentionally .. or by mistake (I'm referring to your 2nd rule -- `R=301` part)?

Comment: That's a mistake, I've been a bit hazy on how the redirect bit works to be honest. You're right I would like to keep the nice url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule -- it will rewrite `/sitemap/` into `/index.php?page=sitemap`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

1. Put it into .htaccess into website root folder. If placed elsewhere it need to be tweaked a bit.
2. URL will stay the same. Existing query string will be preserved.
3. The trailing slash `/` must be present (i.e. `/sitemap` will not trigger this rule).
4. It will only rewrite if there is no such folder or file (i.e. if you have a folder named `sitemap` in your website root folder then no rewrite will occur).
5. It will only work for 1-folder deep URLs (e.g. `/sitemap/`, `/help/`, `/user-account/` etc). It will not work for 2 or more folders in path (e.g. `/account/history/`).

---

**RE: this line:** `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(images|js|css)$`.

You said you want *"exclude any files that contain images|js|css in their uri"*. Unfortunately the above pattern work differently -- it will match `/something/css` but will not match `/css/something` or `/something/file.css`.

If you want to match images|js|css ANYWHERE in URL straight after a slash, then remove `$`.

Comment: Fantastic! That works perfectly now, thanks for the explanation and new rules. What's the best way to 301 redirect index.php?page=sitemap to /sitemap/ now?

Comment: @eb_Dev From SEO point of view you have 2 choices: 1) Use the actual 301 redirect (which is preferred option) or 2) use canonical url (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394). For 301 redirect: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =page=sitemap [NC]` 
`RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sitemap/? [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: Also I have another problem now that I believe is down to my first rule: RewriteRule ^(.*[^/.])$ /$1/ [R=301,L], if i enter http://www.example.com/adadass/ or any file that does not exist it maps it to the homepage and treats it like a page. I figured RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f (or !-d) would prevent this but I must be wrong?

Comment: I wish to go down route 1 and once again that rule works well so thanks for that.

Comment: @eb_Dev This works fine for me to redirect `example.com/hello` to `example.com/hello/`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]` Maybe you have some other rules somewhere? Maybe `DirectorySlash Off` affecting this? -- dunno. If you still having this issue -- formulate it as separate question -- maybe somebody else knows better. P.S. This rule redirects fine for me (am I lucky?)

Comment: Yeah it works but it also works for files / folders that don't exist so example.com/pagethatexists redirects to so example.com/pagethatexists/ which is fine but example.com/pagethatdoesntexist goes to example.com/pagethatdoesntexist/ and the homepage is displayed. I'm sure this would cause SEO problems for loads of URLs that apparently exist but don't. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @eb_Dev Add this rule at the end (before catch all rule, if you have such): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` `RewriteRule .+ /notfound.php [L]`. It will rewrite ALL requests for NONEXISTING files/folders to `/notfound.php` where you handle the rest (send 404 code & display nice error message).

Comment: @eb_dev Or consider using this directive: `ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php`

Comment: Thanks that rule will be useful but unfortunately it doesn't work in this instance as it just indescriminately redirects anything that doesn't exist, so that any request to /pageexists/ that is rewritten to /index.php?page=pageexists will be treated as non-existent because /pageexist/ without be rewritten doesn't point anywhere. Is some sort of chaining rule set in order for this situation?

Comment: I'm already lost. Better ask separate question providing your full current .htaccess and describing which URLs are working and which are not.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help so far, I've learnt a lot! I've posted a new question.